# Creating a relationship between taxonomy lists

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm working on a website about cars, the question is quite simple, but probably, will need as much information as possible.

So here's the situation, I need to create several vocabularies that define a car, starting from a car maker, car model, year, engine, etc... what I need to do is put it in a form of sorts, that filters every section, so say I want Skoda, then in the model, it gives me Fabia/Octavia/Superb/etc... because definitely, A corvette has nothing to do with skoda!!!! then I choose Octavia, and the next list gives me years which it was in production, so it doesn't matter which year I choose the next one is Engine, which engines did it have at that year?

Lets put it in a Graph:

Skoda <- Octavia <- 2000 <- 1.6 8v <- etc...

How do I create the relationship? Do I really need to structure the taxonomy in a very complicated way or what do I do?! Help me, I'm clueless :'( Many websites do it, why is it so complicated on drupal?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this already it's not a very scalable solution, it would require me to put it all in one list, which could go really deep and with no titles as far as I know, per category!

Comment: what you need to do is ajax/ahah your form, where when you enter a level, part of the validation/submission step is grabbing what you need for the next level.  Many websites may do it, but trust me, it's complicated all over, not just drupal ;)

Comment: Depending on what the final goal of your website is, it might be better to do this with Fields/Content types rather than Taxonomy...

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways to do this, in Drupal there are always other ways.  But before you try to implement a solution, ask the question 'what will I want to do with the information besides a direct look up' of say Corvette, year, motor size.  As soon as you find something else you want to include, say various models in a year - coupe, convertible, etc.- or information on colors, performance, displacement, maximum this and that,  you will find yourself redesigning that taxonomy again.  Drupal is a Content Management System and is entirely contained in the database.  Instead of laying out a taxonomy, work on the design of your database.  When you have a good structure for that, start creating fields and use the Views module to generate the content in whatever form you desire. Views is basically a UI for database queries with some great Drupal flexibility for assembling and displaying the content.

I hope this is helpful. By the way, Drupal **is** complicated.  It is very powerful and has a bit of a learning curve.  That's why this site has been successful.  Three months ago, I couldn't even spell Drupal, now I can :)

As you get going, come back to this site for more help.